# Inequality with Euler's totient function

Tags: prime-numbers, conjectures

In [A conjecture concerning primes and algebra](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/995589/a-conjecture-concerning-primes-and-algebra) on MSE, I defined a multiplicative function $\omega:\mathbb Z_+\!\!\to\mathbb Z_+$ with $\omega(p_n)=n$, for the $n$-th prime $p_n$. It was conjectured that $\omega(N)\leq\pi(N)$ for $N>49$, where $\pi$ is the prime-counting function (which seems to be solved by a nice lemma by Greg Martin).

Now I have found another conjecture concerning $\omega$. I have tested $\varphi(N)\geq\omega(N)$ for all $N<1.000.000$, where $\varphi$ is [the Euler totient function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euler%27s_totient_function#Growth_of_the_function), without finding a counterexample.

[image: Totient]

The conjecture, for which I would like a proof or a counter proof, is then:
$\displaystyle
n\prod_{p|n}\left(1-\frac{1}{p}\right)\geq\prod_{k\geq 1}k^{n_k}$, where 
$\displaystyle n=\prod_{k\geq 1}p_k^{n_k}$.

Notes:

- $\varphi$  is multiplicative,  $\varphi(mn)=\varphi(m)\varphi(n)$, for $(m,n)=1$
- $\omega$ is completely multiplicative, $\omega(mn)=\omega(m)\omega(n)$ for all $m,n\in\mathbb Z_+$.
- The inequality $\varphi(N)\geq\pi(N)$ should also be true, for sufficiently large $N$, but I haven't found anything about this on internet.

---

Jaycob Colemans comment seems to prove the inequality:

$\displaystyle
\prod_{p_k,n_k\ne0}\left(1-\frac{1}{p_k}\right)\geq\prod_{p_k,n_k\ne0}\frac{k^{n_k}}{p_k^{n_k}}$, since 
$\displaystyle
\frac{p_k-1}{p_k}\geq\left(\frac{k}{p_k}\right)^{n_k}$.

Comment: This is obviously a well-written post, but what's your question?

Comment: Sorry, the question ask for a proof or a counterproof.

Comment: If you divide both sides by $n$, then isn't this true term by term? $p_k-1\geq k$, so $\dfrac{p_k-1}{p_k}\geq\left(\dfrac k{p_k}\right)^{n_k}$.

Comment: @Jaycob: Yes, except when $n_k=0$, but it works. Thanks!