# A conjecture about the prime counting function

Tags: prime-numbers, conjectures

Using [this lemma](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/995589/a-conjecture-concerning-primes-and-algebra/997522#997522) it can be proved that 
$\Delta(m,n)=\pi(m\cdot n)-\pi(m)\cdot\pi(n)+1$ (where $\pi$ is the prime counting function) 
is a function 
$\Delta:\mathbb N\times\mathbb N\to\mathbb N$.

**Reformulated** conjecture:

> Given $m\in\mathbb N,m>2$, then $n\in \mathbb N$ is an odd prime if 
>   $\Delta(m,n-1)>\Delta(m,n)<\Delta(m,n+1)$ and if $n$ is an odd prime then $\Delta(m,n-1)\ge\Delta(m,n)\le\Delta(m,n+1)$.

The conjecture is tested for $m,n<3000$.

---

**Counterexample**: 
$5879$ is a prime, but $\Delta(5878,5879)=1525672>\Delta(5878,5878)=1523414$

Comment: $\Delta(3,11)=\Delta(3,12)$.

Comment: Thanks @Wojowu, I should have tested it better! I might reformulate.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Suppose $\Delta(m,n-1)>\Delta(m,n)$, then 
$$\pi(mn-m)-\pi(m)\pi(n-1)+1>\pi(mn)-\pi(m)\pi(n)+1\\\pi(m)\pi(n)-\pi(m)\pi(n-1)>\pi(mn)-\pi(mn-m)\geq 0\\\pi(n)>\pi(n-1)$$ so $n$ must be prime, since $\pi(x)$ increases on $n$.

If $n$ is prime, then $\pi(n)=\pi(n-1)+1$, so we can transform $\Delta(m,n-1)\geq\Delta(m,n)$ as follows:
$$\pi(mn-m)-\pi(m)\pi(n-1)+1\geq\pi(mn)-\pi(m)\pi(n)+1\\
\pi(m)\pi(n)-\pi(m)\pi(n-1)\geq\pi(mn)-\pi(mn-m)\\
\pi(m)\geq\pi(mn)-\pi(mn-m)$$
This is equivalent to specific cases of [second Hardy-Littlewood conjecture](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Second_Hardy%E2%80%93Littlewood_conjecture). Obviously we don't get full generality, but nevertheless I seriously doubt anything is known on this. Even though the mentioned conjecture is believed to be false, this special case might just as well be true.

Lastly, if $n$ is odd prime, then $n+1$ isn't, so $\pi(n+1)=\pi(n)$, so transforming $\Delta(m,n+1)\geq\Delta(m,n)$ we easily get
$$\pi(mn+m)\geq\pi(mn)$$
which is clearly true.

To sum up:

> First part of your conjecture is true. Indeed, already $\Delta(m,n-1)>\Delta(m,n)$ implies $n$ is prime.
>
> Primality of $n$ implies $\Delta(m,n+1)\geq\Delta(m,n)$, but whether it implies $\Delta(m,n-1)\geq\Delta(m,n)$ is most likely an open problem.

Comment: I really like the way you solve this kind of problems...

Comment: @Lehs What do you mean? I have just unraveled the definition of $\Delta$ and made some elementary transformations.

Comment: It's easy when it's done. But I never was a good problem solver and now a days I'm rusty and lazy... But, it's never too late to learn and develop.